# Fixing a MacBook's keyboard and trackpad driver in MacOS

Tags: drivers, keyboard, touchpad, macos-highsierra

I have a MacBook Pro from 2015. The keyboard and trackpad are not working under MacOS but when I boot from a bootable USB drive with Ubuntu 16.04 and select "try ubuntu", the keyboard and trackpad *do* work.

Of course, when booting I need to use an external keyboard in order to choose the USB drive as the boot device.

I already tried:

1. Creating a new user account and testing the keyboard there.
2. Resetting the PRAM and SMC
3. Booting in safe mode

Because the keyboard and trackpad work under Ubuntu, I think there is a problem with the drivers of the trackpad and/or the keyboard.

I would like to avoid resetting the whole system. Does somebody have an idea how to fix my problem?

Answer (score 0):

First step would be to try reinstalling macOS from Recovery - this will not change your app or data structure, just 'fix' the OS itself.

Hold  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>R</kbd>  at boot [using your working keyboard, of course]

Comment: I tried what you proposed but it did not fix the keyboard or trackpad. What else could I try?

Comment: Make a new Admin account & test under that.

Comment: It did not help to create the administrator account. Because the mouse and keyboard are not working on the login screen.